# Nginx rewrite downloads php instead of running it

Tags: nginx, php

I have the following code to redirect users visiting login.php to another page:

```
http {
....
geo $bad_user {
  default 0;
  1.2.3.4/32 1;
  4.3.2.1/32 1;
 }

server {
....
location = /login.php {
if ($bad_user) {
rewrite ^ http://example.com/foo.php;
      }
  }
 }
}
```

It makes the login.php file downloaded instead of redirecting users to the other page. All other php files  are working except that file (login.php). And if I removed the above code it works fine, but it won't make the redirection.

I tried the following:

```
      rewrite ^ http://example.com/foo.php last;
```

&

```
      rewrite ^ http://example.com/foo.php$1 last;
```

but none of them worked for me. I also restarted the  whole server but it didn't work.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please attach minimum example of your configure file

Comment: Thanks @Mark , I just updated the question now, please take a look on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a separate location. In your configuration there are no fastcgi directives to handle the case where the user is not a bad_user, thus nginx treats it as a static file and serves it directly.

Instead, put the check in your *existing* `location ~ \.php$` block, and then check for `login.php` there.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($bad_user) {
        rewrite ^/login.php http://example.com/foo.php;
    }
    #....everything else
```

Comment: Than you so much, that worked.